# Shading a certain distance from country borders in google maps

Tags: border, polygon, distance, country

Is it possible to shade an area on a map that lies within a certain distance (say 100km) from a country's border? I anticipate this would be using the polygon tool in some form.

For example, I would like to create a map that shades the area in France that lies within 100km of the border with Germany.

Thank you.